# Nix: adding other derivation's subdirectory to PATH

Tags: nix

I want to make a `foo.nix` file that when you `nix-shell foo.nix` and enter the sand-boxed shell, the PATH includes some other derivation's `bin/` subdirectory. How can I do that?

--- minimal reproducible example ---

Following is my best attempt so far.

This is my current .nix file

```hs
let git = builtins.fetchGit {
        url = https://github.com/ingun37/haskell-script.git;
        rev = "e96ac79d6bf338c98697bb4ba510f22cb5f502ac";
    };
    haskellScriptD = import git {};
in  derivation {
    name = "a"; # giving any name because I won't actually build it.
    builder = "a"; # Same here
    system = builtins.currentSystem;
    script = haskellScriptD;
}
```

and this is what I run in order to run the executable in the derivative's `bin/` subdirectory. You can see I have to append the path before the executable because I don't know how to configure PATH.

```sh
nix-shell a.nix --run "\$script/bin/json-generator"
```

What I want to run is

```sh
nix-shell a.nix --run json-generator
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you really using `derivation` or are you using `stdenv.mkDerivation`?  Instead of pseudocode, could you provide a [mcve] using packages from nixpkgs?  That would be handy because then I can try editing a few lines of it to try some different ideas and see if they work.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I use derivation.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I edited the post to include the actual nix code I use.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Is there a point of using mkDerivation when I'm not actually building it? I only use it to setup a sandboxed shell.

Comment: Hmm... your minimal example pulls in unknown code from the internet and runs it.  Anyway, I think you can just do something like using stdenv.mkDerivation and add the program you are interested in to the `input` or `nativeInputs` attributes, which are supposed to be lists of derivations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidGrayson, I solved it by using *stdenv.mkDerivative* instead of *derivative* and including the derivative into `buildInputs`.

This is the working script

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let git = builtins.fetchGit {
        url = https://github.com/ingun37/haskell-script.git;
        rev = "e96ac79d6bf338c98697bb4ba510f22cb5f502ac";
    };
    haskellScriptD = import git {};
in stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "a";
    buildInputs = [ haskellScriptD ];
}
```

Now I can run

```sh
nix-shell a.nix --run json-generator
```